# Reading JSON result

Tags: json

I have the JSON response below

```
d: {
    __metadata: {...}-
    Items: {
       __metadata: {
          type: "Collection(SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue)"
       }-
       results: [1]
          0:  {
              Label: "Disability ＆ Mental Health"
              TermGuid: "efada5a2-3b92-48ea-91b0-32c7c5f1d85e"
              WssId: 8
         }
    }-
}
```

Does anyone know how to get the Label value using d/results(0) format? Not a big user of the REST service.

Any help is very much appreaciated.

Comment: Do you want to get it using JavaScript? If not, you can just get it by d/results(0)/Label

Comment: Wouldn't it be d/Items/results(0)/Label. I've tried that and it doesn't get me the value.

Comment: I'm using Workflow Designer on VS 2013 btw. I made use of the rest service to get the json.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see the items. Try using d/Items/results/0/Label.

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any idea what the [1] in "results: [1]" means? I can retrieve the title fine but for the Label doesn't seem to work, when traversing the properties is the "Ïtems" property not needed?

Comment: Apparently the [1] is just the count. Since this is a multi value field. I also tried d/Items/results/0/Label. This officially sucks. Lol

Comment: results is an array and 1 is the count of that array. Items is needed since results array is contained within the Items object. Or you can do another thing. You can store the results array in a dictionary like so d/items/results[0]. And you can extract from dictionary and use get item from dictionary action and get the label. Going that route, I think d/Items/results[0]/Label would work.

Comment: Good idea! I'll try this out and let you know. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So weirdly enough the json being returned by sharepoint was of a different format. But I got it by using d/Portfolio/results(0)/Label.